# how to deal with race conditions in a RESTful application?

Tags: java, web-services, design-patterns, rest

Here is what's happening in my RESTful web app:

1. HTTP request comes in
2. The app starts to build a response, with some initial portion of data
3. Another requests changes the data that where used in step 2
4. The first request understands that the data are expired

What should it do? Fail the request and return an error to a client? Or it should start from scratch (taking more time than the client expects)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it not about db transactions and say distributed long running processes are involved in each step.

In this scenario the client should be sent an appropriate response (something like 409/410 http codes) with details indicating that this request is no more valid and the client should try again. Retrying could end up in loops or worst case end up doing what client did not know.

Example, when you book a hotel/ticket online you get a response saying the price has since changed and you need to submit again to buy with new price.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO you should treat a REST request very close to how you treat a DB transaction:

- Either make sure, you lock what to need to lock before doing some real work
- Or prepare to fail/retry on a concurrency issue

Very often this can actually be handed down to a DB transaction - depending on how much and what non-DB work your request does.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good starting point is the concurrency model used by CouchDB. In essence:

- Each request is handled in isolation, i.e. is not affected by other concurrent requests. This implies that you need to be able to get a consistent snapshot of the database when you begin processing a request, which most DBMS systems support with some notion of transaction.
- GET requests always succeed, and return the state of the system at the point when they were submitted, ignoring any subsequent updates.
- GET requests return a revision ID for the resource in question, which must be included as a field in any subsequent PUT request.
- In a PUT request, the submitted revision ID is checked against the latest revision ID in the database. If they don't match then an error code is returned, in which case the client must re-fetch the latest version and re-apply any changes that they made.

More reading:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Technical%20Overview#ACID_Properties
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#PUT

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view your question is the same as like:
"If I try to do a read from the database, and another transaction tries to do a write, it will block. But when I finish my read, I will have missed the new data that will be populated by the new transaction that comes in after my read."
This is a bad way to think about it. You should make sure that the clients get consistent data in the responses. If the data have been updated by the time they get the response that is not problem of the original method.
Your problem is that the data are currently updated, and I happen to know. What if the data are updated right after the response goes out the network?
IMHO choose the simplest solution that fits your requirements.
The clients should "poll" more frequently to make sure they always have the most recent copy of the data

Answer (score -1):

Well strictly speaking a race condition is a bug. The solution to a race condition is not have shared data. If that is not to be avoided for a given use case, then a first come - first serve basis is usually helpful:

The first request locks the shared data and the second waits until the first is done with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "The solution to a race condition is not have shared data.". Most modern web apps are useful *because* they use shared data.